# Label/Street Tile without public transportation

Tags: here-api

I am looking for a way to disable public transportation on a Label/Street tile request. We have a lot of bustops in Copenhagen and they clutter the map and block street names. They have no value in my use-case.

I know that it is possible to use "Map No Public Transport Tile (mapnopttile)", which I do for normal vector maps, but I also need to show roads/labels on my thirdparty WTMS satellite source.

Is this possible? Does HERE have a place to send in feature requests?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please provide us the exact api and request details for us to serve you better.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the mapnopttile. Map No Public Transport Tile (mapnopttile) returns a map tile image without public transport information.  Here is an example:

https://3.base.maps.cit.api.here.com/maptile/2.1/mapnopttile/c98407140a/normal.day/14/8424/5388/256/png8?xnlp=CL_JSMv3.0.17.0&app_id=inCUge3uprAQEtRaruyaZ8&app_code=9Vyk_MElhgPCytA7z3iuPA&lg=ENG&lg2=ENG